# How to run ARM executable file on x86 android emulator?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-emulator

Android emulator already supported run app with ARM binaries on x86 platform: [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#support_for_arm_binaries_on_android_9_and_11_system_images)

> Support for ARM binaries on Android 9 and 11 system images
> If you were previously unable to use the Android Emulator because your app depended on ARM binaries, you can now use the Android 9 x86 system image or any Android 11 system image to run your app – it is no longer necessary to download a specific system image to run ARM binaries. These Android 9 and Android 11 system images support ARM by default and provide dramatically improved performance when compared to those with full ARM emulation.

But wen I run ARM executable binary in the emulator through adb shell, some error happened:

```
emulator64_x86_64_arm64:/data/temp # ./xxx_googletest
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/ndk_translation_program_runner_binfmt_misc_arm64": "/data/temp/lib/liblog.so" is for EM_AARCH64 (183) instead of EM_X86_64 (62)
```

what should I do if I want to run this binary?

Comment: You don't.  ARM code doesn't run on an x86 emulator.  You can use an ARM simulator which simulates an ARM chipset, but expect it to be MUCH slower.  Like close to an order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if the ARM binary is packaged into an APK, it can run on the android studio emulator (x86)。

Comment: Does your binary work properly if you execute it on an arm64 device?